# Can't get Golang to work in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go

Ok, So I've downloaded Go 1.1 and put it into $HOME/Documents/go.

Then, I've modified my `.bashrc` to be:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/go                                                
export GOROOT=$GOPATH
export GOARCH=amd64
export GOOS=linux
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

Than I've sourced the `.bashrc`, and tried:

```
jan@janpc:~$ go version
go version go1.1 linux/amd64
```

But I can't get it to compile or install any dependencies.
Eg. I try to run my little test program:

```
jan@janpc:~/Documents/go/src/github.com/jan/scrypt$ go run scrypt.go 
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/home/jan/Documents/go) has no effect
scrypt.go:9:3: cannot find package "github.com/dchest/scrypt" in any of:
    /home/jan/Documents/go/src/pkg/github.com/dchest/scrypt (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
jan@janpc:~/Documents/go/src/github.com/jan/scrypt$
```

And when I try to install dependencies:

```
jan@janpc:~/Documents/go/src/github.com/jan/scrypt$ go get "github.com/dchest/scrypt"
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/home/jan/Documents/go) has no effect
package github.com/dchest/scrypt: cannot download, $GOPATH must not be set to $GOROOT. For more details see: go help gopath
```

It compiles and works fine on mac. I can't figure out whats wrong with my config, if I try to remove `$GOROOT` or `$GOPATH` nothing works, and I don't know what else to set them to, other than the path to Go.

EDIT:
There is no $GOROOT set on my mac. But if I remove `$GOROOT` on ubuntu, I get bunch of errors like these when I try to compile.

```
cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/fmt (from $GOROOT)
    /home/jan/Documents/go/src/fmt (from $GOPATH)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your enviroment variable you've set by

```
$ export GOROOT=$GOPATH
```

is a mistake. Nowhere is such setting required nor recommended. Actually, it cripples the environment seen by the Go build system.

Remove that setting, recreate your environment (`. bashrc`) or open a new terminal and it should work (if no other problems exists).

Additionally, if you're not cross compiling, I recommend to remove also these:

```
export GOARCH=amd64
export GOOS=linux
```

In short, proper exported GOPATH is the *only* environment variable which is, in the first approximation, really needed. Some more hints [here](http://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment).

EDIT: Okay, so I've downloaded the binary distribution (go1.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz). Quoting from README:

---

> Binary Distribution Notes
>
> If you have just untarred a binary Go distribution, you need to set
>   the environment variable $GOROOT to the full path of the go
>   directory (the one containing this README).  You can omit the
>   variable if you unpack it into /usr/local/go, or if you rebuild
>   from sources by running all.bash (see doc/install.html).
>   You should also add the Go binary directory $GOROOT/bin
>   to your shell's path.
>
> For example, if you extracted the tar file into $HOME/go, you might
>   put the following in your .profile:

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

> See doc/install.html for more details.

---

From this it's clear that you must have not followed properly the above instructions. Fix that and I hope it will work for you then.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake: Double check your new environment using `go env`.

Comment: `echo $GOROOT` is blank, but `go env` reports `GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
`. But there is no /usr/local/go!

Comment: @JanNetherdrake: The build system uses GOROOT if defined or a default otherwise (`/usr/local/go`). This reflects how the GOROOT_FINAL was set when building the Go distribution. It also means, that you must put the distribution in that place. If that directory doesn't exists at your system, it follows that you must have installed it improperly elsewhere. Fix that in the first place ;-)

Comment: I haven't compiled Go myself, I downloaded binaries and pushed them in `~/Documents/`. Is it possible to change it to be in my Documents rather than `/usr/local`?

Comment: @JanNetherdrake: I didn't assumed you built Go from sources. You wouldn't see the problems you're depicting in that case. You seem to use the binary distribution, but it didn't went to the place where the build system expects it. Unfortunately I've never used the binary distribution, so I don't know how it is performed. Is it a simple un-tar to somewhere? Or is there some install script?

Comment: Well, I've put go in `/usr/local`, but now I get back to `$GOPATH must not be set to $GOROOT. For more details see: go help gopath` errors.

Comment: Ok, I've checked Documentation and your new answer, and I think I get it now. Fixed & running. Thanks.

Comment: I think I couldn't quite grasp the requirement of binaries being in `$GOROOT` when they were already in `$GOPATH`. Seems like that was the issue.

Answer (score 18):

Remove any golang package as its undoubtedly obsolete

```
dpkg -l|grep golang  #  if you see any, run following to remove
sudo apt-get purge golang-*
```

To install go it is **CRUCIAL** to first remove prior install (or you will get errors [go build fails : runtime/mstkbar.go:151:10: debug.gcstackbarrieroff undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46009258/147175))

Verify whether go is still installed

```
type go    # see if go is installed
```

typical output if go is installed

```
go is hashed (/usr/local/go/bin/go)
```

if go is installed remove it

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go     #  not just /usr/local/go/bin/go
```

download latest tarball expand and install ... see available versions https://go.dev/dl/ ... below does this for you ... it gets most current release

```
# new_golang_ver=<put desired go version here as in `go1.22.1`>
new_golang_ver=$(curl -s https://go.dev/VERSION?m=text|head -1) # identify current release
echo new_golang_ver is $new_golang_ver
cd /tmp
wget https://go.dev/dl/${new_golang_ver}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf  ${new_golang_ver}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

define these environment variables in your ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:${PATH}
export GOPATH=${HOME}/gopath  # typical value change at will
export PATH=${GOPATH}/bin:${PATH}
```

source your above new env var definitions

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

verify install

```
go version
```

if installed correctly typical output

```
go version go1.12.1 linux/amd64
```

--- **install is complete so lets compile a hello world** ---

```
[[ ! -d $GOPATH ]] && mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/{bin,pkg,src} # if no dir then create
mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/mygithubname/play
cd ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/mygithubname/play
```

now paste following to create the go source file hello_world.go

```
tee hello_world.go  << WOW

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}

WOW
```

compile your source code

```
go build hello_world.go 

./hello_world     #  run your executable
```

> hello, world

---

to understand how to structure your go source code see https://golang.org/doc/code.html

### Fix the missing package error

You also asked how to fix the missing dependency errors ... for example

```
scott@rapacious ~/other_src/gopath/src/github.com/bigeagle/gohop $ go build
hop/cipher.go:27:2: cannot find package "github.com/golang/snappy" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/golang/snappy (from $GOROOT)
    /home/scott/other_src/gopath/src/github.com/golang/snappy (from $GOPATH)
internal/logging.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/op/go-logging" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/op/go-logging (from $GOROOT)
    /home/scott/other_src/gopath/src/github.com/op/go-logging (from $GOPATH)
```

above error will happen even after your go install is setup OK ... just issue this to download and install the missing upstream dependency go packages (and the ones they might also reference recursively)

```
cd ~/Documents/go/src/github.com/jan/scrypt/ # cd into the source dir
go get -v -t ./...   #  -v  verbose
                     #  -t  also download any test only packages
go build
```

Answer (score 9):

TLDR:  **Unset `$GOROOT`** by running following **command in your terminal `export GOROOT=""`**

I had Go installed on Ubuntu 16.04 and everything was working fine.

Then by mistake I set the `$GOROOT` to `$GOPATH` following a tutorial, at which point my build started to fail saying:

```
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT has no effect
cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
... (from $GOROOT) ($GOPATH not set)
cannot find package "io/ioutil" in any of:
imports runtime: cannot find package "runtime" in any of:
/home/mhsn/go/src/runtime (from $GOROOT)
($GOPATH not set)
```

Every solution I read was suggesting to not set this variable, and I wanted to unset this. I found the following fix to get it unset: `export GOROOT=""` in bash.

Having unset the `$GOROOT` back to empty which was recommended by everyone so go defaulted back to original path. And it fixed the issue for me and go build started to work again.

Answer (score 2):

You should not set $GOROOT for normal installations.

Just type `export GOROOT=""` and it should fix your problem.