# How to make "godoc" command work on my system?

Tags: ubuntu, go, environment-variables

"godoc" doesnt' work on my system.(I'm using ubuntu 13.04)

```
godoc fmt
```

gives the following error

```
2013/06/08 19:12:43 readTemplate: open /usr/lib/go/lib/godoc/codewalk.html: no such file or directory
```

"which go" gives:

```
/usr/bin/go
```

"go env" gives the following:

```
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="386"
GOCHAR="8"
GOOS="linux"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: How and where have you installed Go? What does eg. `$ which go` say?

Comment: @jnml it gives "/usr/bin/go"

Comment: I suppose you have used the binary distribution. If you would untar it to `/usr/lib/go` than you cannot have the `go` binary in `/usr/bin/go`. I think you've not followed properly the instructions in the README file. See it discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16977772/1065241)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install golang-doc
godoc -http=:6060
```

Navigate to `http://localhost:6060`

---

**EDIT**: The version shipped with the distribution is likely to be out of date.  I'm not an active Go user at the moment but this answer looks the most complete: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61300854/15985

Comment: This starts a webserver with the web documentation. The Problem here is to get the docs in the shell.

Comment: Many distributions, including Ubuntu 19.10 still ship with totally outdated godoc versions which fail on Go modules. It is thus recommended to install directly from source using `go get -v  golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`. Roney Thomas answer thus should be the accepted answer, but not this one due to it recommending installing broken and outdated system packages.

Answer (score 83):

Install godoc by using go install

```
go install -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc@latest
```

Comment: it doesn't work, but `go get -v  golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc` runs well.

Comment: That's the best solution I've found so far, thank you

Comment: This should now the accepted answer as godoc is maintained and updatd separately; as many distributions still ship outdated godoc OS packages which fail to handle GO modules, installing from source is important.

Comment: Works as of today!

Comment: what is the `-v` flag for?

Comment: `-v` means CLI output will be verbose, so I guess `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc` should also work.

Answer (score 25):

As has been pointed out by others some changes in Go 1.2 have caused the debian package maintainers to make some changes. The current way to install godoc is

```
sudo apt-get install golang-go.tools
```

This is because the Go developers moved godoc out of the normal distribution and into the go.tools subrepo. This subrepo is updated more frequently and has different rules for backwards compatibility.

---

---

**Old answer:**

It looks like you installed from the ubuntu package. You need to install golang-doc package in order to use godoc. This is installed automatically if you install the golang metapackage.

```
sudo apt-get install golang
```

---

If you use packages to install Go, I also recommend installing from the gophers PPA. Current packages are very old. The current is 1.0.2 when 1.0.3 was the final 1.0 release and 1.1 is the current version number. Details can be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Go.

Comment: godoc is not installed with the `golang` package by default.  It is located in `golang-go.tools`.

Comment: on Ubuntu 15.10 installing golang-go.tools doesn't populate the godoc tool with any information. The tool itself if there, but useless until I installed `golang-godoc`.

Answer (score 19):

**Simplest way**:

1. First, install `godoc` with following command:

   ```
   go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
   ```
2. Start `godoc` server:

   ```
   godoc -http=:6060
   ```
3. In your browser, visit:

   ```
   http://localhost:6060
   ```

Comment: This answer surely deserves an upvote! This works very well.

Answer (score 9):

You need to install the `golang-go.tools` package.

`sudo apt-get install golang-go.tools`

Answer (score 3):

in ubuntu 14.04 have to install `golang`,`golang-doc` and `golang-go.tools` :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang
sudo apt-get install golang-doc
sudo apt-get install golang-go.tools
```

and for use, run :

```
godoc -http=:6060
```

and open `localhost:6060` in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sudo apt install golang-golang-x-tools` to install go doc on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall golang

```
apt-get purge golang*
```

Download compiled go archive from https://golang.org/dl/

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xvf go1.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
mv go /usr/local
```

The `mv`ing is not really necessary, though. You could just create a symlink `/usr/local/go` pointing to your go installation directory.

`sudo ln -s $GO_HOME /usr/local/go`

You may need to set Go Paths. Then you can test your install.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
go version
```

`godoc` should be usable now.

Comment: Great answer! For those who don't prefer to use their Distro's package

Comment: Go 1.13 -- `godoc` is not bunded. Some tuning required, posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (I prefer to install Go by hand in `/usr/local/go`):

```
$ sudo -i
root# unset GOPATH
root# go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
root# which godoc
/usr/local/go/bin/godoc
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is a very clean way of doing this, thanyou.

Comment: I did need to add "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" to the commands

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora:

`sudo dnf install golang-godoc`

`godoc -http=localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

I've installed go and also havn't godoc, but I see:
go doc fmt

(go doc - I see from go help)